# Postgres Query to return more than just array_agg

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

This is how the data is formatted:

```
item_name | item_serial | sub_group | conc_stuff | other_data | more_data
----------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------
foo        bar-01-a      widget      b-3          towel        dent
foo        bar-02-a      widget      a-1          42           mouse
foo        bar-03-a      widget      p-1          babel        dolphin
foo3       bar-21-f      widget      f-1          42           marvin
foo3       bar-22-f      widget      x-1          poetry       vogon
```

I have gotten the query to perform the way I want it to, the problem is I need to return more data.

```
SELECT item_name, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(conc_stuff), ',') as stuff 
FROM dataset 
WHERE some_selector = 'X' 
GROUP BY item_name 
ORDER BY item_name;
```

I have tried what seems simple yet logical to me:

```
SELECT item_name, 
       item_serial, 
       sub_group, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(conc_stuff), ',') as stuff 
FROM dataset 
WHERE some_selector = 'X' 
GROUP BY item_name 
ORDER BY item_name;
```

I need to return something that looks like this:

```
item_name | item_serial | sub_group |   stuff
----------+-------------+-----------+-------------
foo        bar-01-a      widget      a-1,b-3,p-1
foo3       bar-21-f      widget      f-1,x-1,g-5
foo6       bar-81-z      widget      r-1,d-8,w-0
```

instead of just this:

```
item_name |   stuff
----------+--------------
foo        a-1,b-3,p-1
foo3       f-1,x-1,g-5
foo6       r-1,d-8,w-0
```

When I try to add additional fields to the query, I get :

`ERROR:  column "stuff.item_serial" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

But I dont want to `GROUP BY` item_serial, I just want it to be returned with the aggregate, right?

Do I need to run a subquery? Im sure this is simple. The if there are multiple  methods, which is most efficient? Some of the text I will be concatenating are coordinates (LARGE string of text).

Comment: Is `item_serial` a unique column? If there is more than one `item_serial` for a given `item_name` value, which one should be displayed?

Comment: none of the columns are, all basic. there can be multiple item_serials that belong to different sub_group

Comment: So which item_serial (or sub_group) do you want to take for a specific `item_name`?

Comment: very sorry I just noticed that error... editing

Comment: Again then: which `item_serial` do you want to see for the name `foo`?

Comment: I am confusing the issue. My problem is the format of the data, and likely first normal form as well. The initial question was answered. Thanks for your help @a_horse_with_no_name!!!!

Comment: But the accepted answer will not return your example output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick one value for each name you have. You can't have each name only returned once but the `item_serial` value multiple times.

Picking one value out of those that are there for a group value is done through aggregate functions:

```
SELECT item_name,
       min(item_serial),
       min(sub_group),
       array_to_string(array_agg(conc_stuff),',') AS stuff
FROM dataset
WHERE sub_group = 'widget'
GROUP BY item_name
ORDER BY item_name;
```

This picks th4e "first" `item_serial` and `sub_group` for each name.

If you want the last value, use `max` instead.

But the important thing to understand is that you have to pick one value for the non-grouped columns. And you need to tell the DBMS exactly which one it should use by supplying an aggregate function which picks **one** value.

SQLFiddle example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/58009/1

Comment: brilliant! this solves the secondary issue! I  checked slightly too soon! though @greg did supply a correct solution for the question I asked. I apologize for the confusion. and +10 for introducing me to sqlfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Postgres 8.4 is somewhat stricter than more recent versions of Pg regarding this. When using a `GROUP BY`, all fields not containing an aggregate functions need to be grouped.

From Pg9.1, if you `GROUP BY` primary key, all other non grouped fields can be omitted.

Hope it helps.

Edit:

```
SELECT 
  item_name, 
  item_serial, 
  sub_group, 
  array_to_string(array_agg(conc_stuff), ',') as stuff 
FROM 
  dataset 
WHERE 
  some_selector = 'X' 
GROUP BY 
  item_name,
  item_serial,
  sub_group 
ORDER BY 
  item_name;
```

Comment: so I can select the others if I `group by` even though I dont need them grouped? Now I see the example it makes sense. Ill try this method, thanks!

Comment: your answer solves the issue I started with, though after posting I realized that wasnt my issue. it was a faulty line of logic on my part.